# How to omit if variable is empty in Ansibe?

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm going through [ansible example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html#examples) for Docker.

And I need to publish a port just like in the example but with an if statement `if port else omit`. Like this:

```
docker_container:
name: myapplication
...
ports:
 - "{{ if port else omit }}" # the {{ port }} variable is set from the default task.
...
```

But each time I run this, the Docker daemon tells me:

```
template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'port'. String: {{ if port else omit }}"
```

How do I omit setting the port if the variable `{{ port }}` is empty?

Thanks kindly for your help in advance.

Comment: You should accept an answer, if it solves your issue and I think β.εηοιτ.βε answer does it

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`default` filter with the `omit` variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) for that.

```yaml
- docker_container:
    name: myapplication
    ports: "{{ port|default(omit) if port is not defined else [port] }}"
```

Mind that you want to use this exact syntax and not the array notation like

```yaml
- docker_container:
    name: myapplication
    ports:
      - "{{ port|default(omit) }}"
```

Otherwise you will end up with an array in the attribute `ports`, still, that would have some odd value like

```
"__omit_place_holder__ad3616ee8afa39aa187d7fc6ac7ad36f3e7691c0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` for conditional plays. Define your container first:

```
docker_container:
  name: myapplication
  ...
```

If port is defined expose it:

```
docker_container:
  name: myapplication
  ports:
   - "{{ port }}"
  when: port is defined
```